# aspectj issue after update to java 8

Tags: java, java-8, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

Trying to upgrade a multi-repository project to java 8... We use aspectj, via the maven plugin. First problem was obvious, needed to update aspectj runtime (and the maven plugin) because the old version didn't understand the new class files.

One of the things our aspectj setup should take care of is automatic logging of method calls. This still works for most classes -- *except* some classes that are being added to a pre-existing package (which is brought in as `weaveDependency` from another repository).

Methods from such classes, and *only* these methods, are now missing  missing from our logs.

Honestly I have no idea how to even begin tracking this down, so any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: I have no idea either because you neither share your POM nor infos about your library or weaving logs. Please update the question and help others to help you.

Comment: @kriegaex I am aware I didn't give a lot to go on. Unfortunately this is happening in a complicated multi-module maven setup and I can't easily distill something that I can share here. I understand this makes it more difficult for people to help -- but I'd hoped that the pattern I described (of adding classes to an external package) might ring a bell for someone.

Comment: I dare to challenge your assumption. I think it should be possible to extract something or rebuild a minor showcase for the problem from scratch. It might even give you insight into your problem's root cause. Give it a go! This is StackOverflow, we deal with code here. ;-) The reason I am saying this is that I do not have any Java 8 issues with AspectJ whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I might have some time to attempt what you suggest later this week -- agree that this might itself provide clues. For now I've found a dumb workaround that allowed me to get onto what I am really supposed to be doing :-)

Comment: Would you mind sharing or describing the workaround? Maybe I can conclude the problem's root cause from it. I do like puzzles.

Comment: Sure. I stopped adding classes to an existing package from another repository, and instead moved them to the same repository. This is not a long-term solution because the separation was there for a reason -- but it allows me to continue with the more urgent tasks at hand.

Comment: This does not sound like an AspectJ problem related to version upgrade. Did the exact same setup work with an older AspectJ version? This is hard to believe.